# Hosting Flask App on Centos with Apache

Tags: python, apache, flask, centos

Very new to this.

I am trying to follow along with [this](https://mitchjacksontech.github.io/How-To-Flask-Python-Centos7-Apache-uWSGI/) tutorial.

The main difference to my setup is that I am not using a domain, but would rather just access the flask site (something for personal use only) through the ip address.

This step:

> Test sample flask app: If you want, test yourself for typos. uwsgi --socket 0.0.0.0:5000 --protocol=http -w wsgi

... works and I can access the flask app at ipaddress:5000

My /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf ServerName is configured with the ipaddress rather than *flaskdemo.com*

Problematically though once I spin up the apache service with

```
sudo systemctl start httpd
```

... I get a 503 at ipaddress

Thanks in advance for any support.

Comment: `*:80` apache `0.0.0.0:5000`(mean`*:5000`) The name of the server specified is valid, whichever comes last.  Open a separate loopback or identify the publishing IP address. Loopback can hold more than one publication, but cannot carry more than one name. Independent services do not connect to fixed services. like this :  `uwsgi --socket your_IP_local_or_global:5000`

Comment: not really following what you're saying I'm afraid.

Comment: The tutorial is running uwsgi with port 5000 for testing and 8000 for production, ensure the later is running before going to apache, 

Apache is doing http and passing to the uwsgi app on the backend.

Internet --> Apache --> uwsgi

Comment: thanks for the reply. How do I ensure the later is running before going to apache?